# How to derive the model equation from the probabilistic neural network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Suppose I am using the MATLAB probabilistic neural network example for a classification problem, as given ([click here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/pnn-classification.html))

The weights and the bias for the network can be determined as follows;

```
weights = net.LW
biases = net.b
```

My question is, how do I get an equations describing the model. I am a beginner in neural network, any detailed explanation/sample code would be most helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this question shows complete lack of undertanding of the very basis of NNs, so it will be very difficult to actually help you here, because you need a tutorial, not an answer to your question. I suggest you read a bit about NNs

Comment: if you use the ntstool and click "generate matlab function" on the second last page you get the formula that the NN came up with, but as mentioned by @AnderBiguri you might need more insight on the conecpt of NN